# Using the SqlParameterSource list in batchUpdate to batch delete data, use 2 value in sql, but the NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils parse it as 3

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

The sql is `"delete from TABLE where id1 = :id1 and id2 in(:id2s)"`,
and create List mapSqlParameterSources, then
`SqlParameterSource[] paras = mapSqlParameterSources.toArray(new SqlParameterSource[0])`. The size of the list 'id2s' in test example is two. Then try to update db by  `db.batchUpdate(sql, paras);`

When testing the code, the IDEA throws java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3. And the console show the sql is parsed into `"delete from TABLE where id1 = ? and id2 in(?, ?)"`
But when update one by one such as `db.batchUpdate(sql, paras[0]);`  , the sql will execute right and delete the data in db.

Comment: (show your prepare statement)

Comment: Please show some actual full code instead of snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Done, it's a bad case in lower version spring-boot.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21935